# "Could not open macro storage" when accessing using file on another machine

Tags: c#, office-interop

I have Office 2013 installed on a Windows 2008 R2 Enterprise machine, In a C# windows service application running as administrator,I use the method "Word.Documents.Add" to process word documents and it works fine with documents on that machine by giving it the UNC path of the file.

```
object oTemplate = p_strUNCFilePath;
object readOnly = false;
object isVisible = true;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document oWordDoc = m_WordApp.Documents.Add(ref oTemplate, ref readOnly, ref readOnly, ref isVisible);
```

However if the file exists on a remote share on another machine on same domain, i get the error message "Could not open macro storage" .The word application process uses administrator account and the share that contains the file has full control for everyone for share & NTFS permissions.

Please advise what to do.

Answer (score 3):

Check the properties of the word document and make sure the files are unblocked. Sometimes when you get the documents from a different computer or download them from the internet they will be blocked which will cause the the throwing of this exception "could not open macro storage"